# Arcgis 10.2.2 soap API Error {401 - Unauthorized}

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, security

I'm trying to consume secured map service via arcgis 10.2.2 soap api. I've configured my web adapter to negotiate windows domain security and everything looks fine when I check over the rest api. However I get a this exception when I try to consume the same service with soap api. I'm getting 401-unauthorized at getDefaultMapName method.

```
 mapServer = new MapServerBindingStub(uri, username, password);
 defaultMapName = mapServer.getDefaultMapName(); //<error here 401-unauthorized>
```

Error

```
Caused by: com.esri.arcgisws.runtime.exception.ArcGISWebServiceException: HTTP s
tatus code {401 - Unauthorized} received from server
        at com.esri.arcgisws.runtime.transport.http.HttpClientConnectionChannelI
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem here. I've setup webadaptor according to esri's [spec](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Securing_web_services_with_Integrated_Windows_Authentication/015400000517000000/) but soap stubs aren't seem to be handling windows (NTLM) negotiation properly. Basically arcgis stubs aren't responding to challenge therefore it remains as unauthorized response for the application. I've changed the authentication to be "Basic" and negotiation started working happily.